# Python Date(yyyymmdd) - 5 ( skipping saturday,sunday)

Tags: python

I have to create one logic in python, want to pass date and get difference from it of like 5 dates excluding weekends. Date format will be YYYYMMDD.

Passed - 20230228
expected date after logic - 20230221 Passed-5(excluding weekend)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code of logic? Please add code of what you have try.

Answer (score 2):

To get the expected date excluding weekends this code helps you.

```
import datetime

def get_previous_date(date_str, days_to_subtract):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y%m%d').date()
    weekdays_to_subtract = days_to_subtract

    while weekdays_to_subtract > 0:
        date -= datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        if date.weekday() < 5: # check if the day is a weekday
            weekdays_to_subtract -= 1

    return date.strftime('%Y%m%d')

print(get_previous_date("20230228",5))
```

**Result:**

```
20230221
```

Comment: Thanks Nikunj for the quick resolution, your help is much appreciated.